# MysqlDump is getting Error : ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist (1449)

Tags: mysql

I am running a mysqldump in my centos 7 terminal which has my mysql server setup.(with working sites),
it shows the following errors.

> mysqldump: Error: 'The user specified as a definer
> ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist' when trying to dump
> tablespaces
>
> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW DATABASES': The user specified as a
> definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist (1449)

then tried logged in as the root user and "SHOW DATABASES" I got the following error

> ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer
> ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

Also with the command "CREATE USER TEST" I get the error

> ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system

any directions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is the solution.
I tried updating the MySQL by

```
yum update MySQL
```

it will only update the MySQL client so we need to update both client and the server

so I used

> yum update mysql* -y

then it updates both of them. and the issue fixed now.
Thanks.